# Is it possible to drop a tcp connection and not receive a notification/exception

Tags: c#, networking

I'm currently working with the assumption that when sending TCP data with System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Send ,I am guaranteed to get an exception if the connection drops. Is it possible to have a connection drop at the OS layer without receiving a notification/exception in the C# application on top?

I don't imagine there is such a case, in .net, but how would I go about demonstrating this to someone that is skeptical.

Comment: Using TCP, there is no such thing as "a packet". TCP is a stream-oriented protocol, meaning the data is just one big stream of bytes. If you receive data until end-of-stream (receive operation completes with 0 bytes), you can be 100% positive that all of the data that was sent to you has in fact been received. Of course, if you terminate the connection forcibly, or if you are keeping the connection open, and are wondering if you've received everything that's been sent so far, no...there is no way to know for sure you have.

Comment: If you are the sender, then the only way to know for sure that the remote endpoint has received your data is to ask it. Of course, one way to do this is for your application level protocol to require that the remote endpoint leave its connection open until it's received all of the data you sent. In that case, receiving the end-of-stream _from_ the remote endpoint informs the sender that they've received everything. But obviously this works for data going in one direction; it's not possible for both endpoints to know each has received each other's data, without additional negotiation.

Comment: When I say packet, I'm referring to an IP datagram containing a TCP segment.

Comment: _"I'm referring to an IP datagram containing a TCP segment"_ -- I don't see how. Sockets don't send those per se, though of course the underlying network layer turns the client transmissions into them. But, whatever. Those get dropped all the time. The point of TCP is that the client code never sees that. The protocol ensures dropped IP datagrams are resent, and received by the client in the correct order.

Comment: You've made me think about this and it makes sense why we trust the TCP layer, but I'd still like to have an understanding of reliability of the entire stack. What about .net failing to pick up on a dropped connection from the OS layer. I'm starting to think that if there ever were such cases within .net, they'd patched by now.

Comment: _"What about .net failing to pick up on a dropped connection from the OS layer"_ -- that would be a bug, and far beyond unlikely. Never mind that there are way too many `Socket`-based programs out there (I'd guess tens of thousands of "serious" ones, and probably at least 100's of thousands of others), and that `Socket` itself is a very thin layer over Winsock, which it itself has been in use for more than two decades. The thing you really need to worry about is your own code. It's probably about a million times more likely to contain a bug than the `Socket` class is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually as far as i know It is possible. Imagine you create a packet send it and it gets dropped by the way. Os should automatically retransmit when ttl timesout. It will retry few times before giving up. More advanced firewalls have one small option as I remember. Drop with or without notification. Second looks like packet was 'lost' on the way to destination. They actually receive it but let's say- sends them to null without any answer.
 I do not know how exactly socket.send works but from network point of view it is possible to not get confirmation for every packet that was lost/dropped.